# Peek into protocol buffer message files

Tags: serialization, command-line, protocol-buffers

Is there a command line tool to peek into files containing several protocol buffer messages (of the same message type)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still need such tools, we've build it: http://temk.github.io/protobuf-utils/

Answer (score 0):

It should be trivial to write your own if you know the `Message` type.  For example, in C++ you could use [`Message::DebugString()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message.DebugString) or the [`Printer`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.printer) class.

Note that if a single file contains several serialised `Message`s, you'll need to handle parsing them back in correctly since `ParseFromIstream`, `ParseFromFileDescriptor`, etc. all parse the entire file.  I guess you could do this by wrapping your existing `Message` in a new `Message` which only contained a single repeated field of the existing `Message` type.